# How do I stop the Tempfile created by Creek from being deleted before I'm done with it?

Tags: ruby, garbage-collection

I'm writing a script that Creek and an .xlsx file and uses it to update the prices and weights of products in a database. The .xlsx file is located on an AWS server, so Creek copies the file down and stores it in a Tempfile while it is in use.

The issue is, at some point the Tempfile seems to be prematurely deleted, and since Creek continues to call on it whenever it iterates through a sheet, the script fails. Interestingly, my coworker's environment runs the script fine, though I haven't found a difference between what we're running.

Here is the script I've written:

```
require 'creek'

class PricingUpdateWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(filename)
    # This points to the file in the root bucket
    file = bucket.files.get(filename)

    # Make public temporarily to open in Creek
    file.public = true
    file.save

    creek_sheets = Creek::Book.new(file.public_url, remote: true).sheets

    # Close file to public
    file.public = false
    file.save

    creek_sheets.each_with_index do |sheet, sheet_index|
      p "---------- #{sheet.name} ----------"

      sheet.simple_rows.each_with_index do |row, index|
        next if index == 0

        product = Product.find_by_id(row['A'].to_i)
        if product
          if row['D']&.match(/N\/A/) || row['E']&.match(/N\/A/)
            product.delete
            p '*** deleted ***'
          else
            product.price = row['D']&.to_f&.round(2)
            product.weight = row['E']&.to_f
            product.request_for_quote = false
            product.save
            p 'product updated'
          end
        else
          p "#{row['A']} | product not found ***"
        end
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def connection
    @connection ||= Fog::Storage.new(
      provider: 'AWS',
      aws_access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      aws_secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    )
  end

  def bucket
    # Grab the file from the bucket
    @bucket ||= connection.directories.get 'my-aws-bucket'
  end
end
```

And the logs:

```
"---------- Sheet 1 ----------"
"product updated"
"product updated"
... I've cut out a bunch more of these...
"product updated"
"product updated"
"---------- Sheet 2 ----------"
rails aborted!
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /var/folders/9m/mfcnhxmn1bqbm6h91rx_rd8m0000gn/T/file20190920-19247-c6x4zw
```

"/var/folders/9m/mfcnhxmn1bqbm6h91rx_rd8m0000gn/T/file20190920-19247-c6x4zw" is the temporary file, and as you can see, it's been collected already, even though I'm still using it, and I believe it is still in scope. Any ideas what could be causing this? It's especially odd that my coworker can run this just fine.

In case it's helpful, here is a little code from Creek:

```
def initialize path, options = {}
      check_file_extension = options.fetch(:check_file_extension, true)
      if check_file_extension
        extension = File.extname(options[:original_filename] || path).downcase
        raise 'Not a valid file format.' unless (['.xlsx', '.xlsm'].include? extension)
      end
      if options[:remote]
        zipfile = Tempfile.new("file")
        zipfile.binmode
        zipfile.write(HTTP.get(path).to_s)
        # I added the line below this one, and it fixes the problem by preventing the file from being marked for garbage collection, though I shouldn't need to take steps like that.
        # ObjectSpace.undefine_finalizer(zipfile)
        zipfile.close
        path = zipfile.path
      end
      @files = Zip::File.open(path)
      @shared_strings = SharedStrings.new(self)
    end
```

EDIT: Someone wanted to know exactly how I was running my code, so here it is.

I run the following rake task by executing `bundle exec rails client:pricing_update[client_updated_prices.xlsx]` in the command line.

```
namespace :client do
  desc 'Imports the initial database structure & base data from uploaded .xlsx file'
  task :pricing_update, [:filename] => :environment do |t, args|
    PricingUpdateWorker.new.perform(args[:filename])
  end
end
```

I should also mention that I'm running Rails, so the Gemfile.lock keeps the gem versions consistent between me and my coworker. My fog version is 2.0.0 and my rubyzip version is 1.2.2.

Comment: what happens if you move the 2 lines after `# Close file to public` until after your loop finishes?

Comment: lacostenycoder I'm afraid nothing different happens.

Comment: I deleted my answer because after doing some more tests with a public xlsx file I was able to get a more basic example to work with no errors. Can I ask HOW you're running your code?  Also what versions of Fog and rubyzip gems are you running? Make sure they are the same as what is running on Heroku or working machine.

Comment: @lacostenycoder I've updated my post with the answers to your question.

Comment: if you are running this from rake and not using `.perform_async` do you even need `include Sidekiq::Worker` ?  But I don't think that is your problem.

Comment: See my updated answer.  The bug seems to be bad formatting or handling of unknown source or encoding in the XLSX file.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it seems that the bug is not in Creek gem at all but rather in the rubyzip gem having trouble with xlsx files as noted in [this issue](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip/issues/288) It seems to depend on how the source of the file was generated. I created a simple 2 page spreadsheet in Google sheets and it works fine, but a random xlsx file may not.

```
require 'creek'

def test_creek(url)
  Creek::Book.new(url, remote: true).sheets.each_with_index do |sheet, index|
    p "----------Name: #{sheet.name} Index: #{index} ----------"
    sheet.simple_rows.each_with_index do |row, i|
        puts "#{row} index: #{i}"
    end
  end
end

test_creek 'https://tc-sandbox.s3.amazonaws.com/creek-test.xlsx'
# works fine should output
"----------Name: Sheet1 Index: 0 ----------"
{"A"=>"foo ", "B"=>"sheet", "C"=>"one"} index: 0
"----------Name: Sheet2 Index: 1 ----------"
{"A"=>"bar", "B"=>"sheet", "C"=>"2.0"} index: 0

test_creek 'http://dev-builds.libreoffice.org/tmp/test.xlsx'
# raises error
```

Comment: I also commented [this issue in the repo](https://github.com/pythonicrubyist/creek/issues/28#issuecomment-533795099)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, this isn't working for me. It doesn't explain why the code might work on someone else's setup either, which is part of the puzzle.

Comment: @Dinopolis are the other person's setup using the same versions of everything?  We have no idea of your dependency chain. But I can tell you that I tested similar striped down code with a test xlsx file on S3 and creating a file locally instead of dealing with tempfile worked fine for me.

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes. They're using the same branch with the same gem specifications, and they're using the same version of Ruby (2.5.1). The code also works when deployed to Heroku. When I run your code I get an error telling me that the file is not a valid format.

Comment: What is the exact error?  If it's encoding than try to leave out `"w:ASCII-8BIT"` and just pass `w` to write the file.   But also, when testing on Heroku or other machine, are you testing with the same exact file on S3 ?